# Starting GeoServer on OSGeoLive automatically

Tags: geoserver, osgeo-live

I want to use OSGeo Live VM 8.0 as a test GeoServer. Following [its website](http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/geoserver_quickstart.html), I started the server by

> Select the Geospatial ‣ Web Services ‣ GeoServer ‣ Start GeoServer in
>   the menu

But after rebooting the server, geoserver is down again.

How do I start geoserver automatically as if I installed geoserver myself on a fresh Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out by tracing the various shortcuts in Lubuntu. Basically, it involves creating a init script in `/etc/init.d` as listed in the bottom, which starts `tomcat` and call the content of the osgeo geoserver start script. Note: restarting tomcat is not good enough as I had thought.

After that do:

```
update-rc.d myscript defaults 99 01
```

Init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myscript
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)

    service tomcat6 restart
    /usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.5/bin/startup.sh

    ;;
esac

quit 0
```

-- UPDATE --

After some digging, I found that OSGeoLive (8.0) favor of GeoServer is powered by jetty, not tomcat, though both are installed. That explains why starting tomcat does not start geoserver.

Comment: Just to clarify; isn't GS a webapp of tomcat? if its properly installed it should be serving data after tomcat starts

Comment: That's what I thought. But on my OSGeoLive VM, GeoServer didn't start with tomcat6. Really don't know why.